# Why is my render darker after joining geometry?

Tags: rendering, transparency, geometry, glass

[image: Example]

I am working on cleaning up an asset I purchased of a closet (above). I am currently trying to join the closet doors together (frames + glass pane), but when I do so the render gets darker for some reason.

### Before Joining:

[image: Before Join]

### After Joining:

[image: After Join]

The difference is subtle, so I would suggest opening both the before and after images in separate tabs and flipping through them quickly. I checked my normals and they are fine.

Any help at all would be extremely appreciated as I am completely stumped.

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: It might have something to do with the IOR of the Principled BSDF on your glass material. Try lowering it slightly (maybe 1.2 - 1.25?).

Comment: I'll give it a shot. But why would that make a difference if the IOR is the same both pre and post join? Just a note - I'm not really searching for a "good result" as much as I'm trying to understand exactly what's going on behind the scenes. I.E. *why* is the joined mesh render darker.

Comment: I'm not sure - perhaps blender handles refraction differently when the object is larger (because all the pieces are now joined), and therefore has a slightly larger (or different shape) bounding box.

Comment: Interesting thought, I hadn't considered that. Thanks. The geometry of the doors is a little dodgy anyway, I think I might just re-model them. I think they were modeled in max and the actual glass pane doesn't have any thickness, so I'm not really getting an accurate result anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was happening. Shadow ray visibility was disabled for the glass. When I merged the glass with the frame, shadow ray visibility got enabled again.

[image: Ray Visibility]